# Clojure: Why a function should be `declare` if it is called before definition in the source code

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, if you call a function before its definition, e.g.

```
(foo (bar 'a))

(defn bar [] ...)
```

it is not compiled. One should add

```
(declare bar)
```

before `(foo (bar 'a))`. Why Clojure is designed as this? I mean, in most languages, except C/C++, such as Java, Python, PHP, Scala, Haskell or even other Lisps, especially in dynamic-type languages, function declaration is not needed, that is, function definition could be put either before or after a call. I feel it uncomfortable to use.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Clojure does a single-pass compilation (well I simplify, read the following links) :

- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2467359
- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2466912

So it seems logical that if you read the source only one time, from top to bottom you cannot have things like forward declaration *and* do it safely.

To quote Rich (first link) :

> But, what should happen here, when the compiler has never before seen
>   bar?
>
> ```
> `(defn foo [] (bar))`
> ```
>
> or in CL:
>
> ```
> `(defun foo () (bar))`
> ```
>
> CL happily compiles it, and if bar is never defined, a runtime error will occur. Ok, but, what reified thing
>   (symbol) did it use for bar during compilation? The symbol it interned
>   when the form was read. So, what happens when you get the runtime
>   error and realize that bar is defined in another package you forgot to
>   import. You try to import other-package and, BAM!, another error -
>   conflict, other-package:bar conflicts with read-in-package:bar. Then
>   you go learn about uninterning.
>
> In Clojure, the form doesn't compile,
>   you get a message, and no var is interned for bar. You require
>   other-namespace and continue.
>
> I vastly prefer this experience, and so
>   made these tradeoffs. Many other benefits came about from using a
>   non-interning reader, and interning only on definition/declaration.
>   I'm not inclined to give them up, nor the benefits mentioned earlier,
>   in order to support circular reference.

Comment: Excellent that you dug out these old HN posts with the explanations by Rich Hickey. I was looking to find them again for a long time.

Comment: It also means you are forced to read code in a consistent manner i.e. from the bottom to the top. If you look at a function then you know that all the declarations inside it will be above it in the namespace, just a small thing but it's useful when reading code.