# Does declare function cause any performance problems in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

As you know we need to use `declare` function if we want to use a function without declaring it before so my question is using `declare` function causes any performance issues?

Clojure has `single pass compilation` so it has to do some kind of tradeoffs over there I assume?

Comment: Clojure does not exactly have a single pass compilation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33144157/1327651

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clojure doesn't have a single pass complier, it's just that the compilation unit is not a file. For reference see [this thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2467809). All declare does is define a var with no value in the current namespace, so that it can be redefined later. There is therefore no performance impact over normal vars.

However, if you start looking at optimising your code, you might start to add things like defining an inline version of some of your code, anything that's compiled between the declare call and the definition of the inline function will not have that call inlined.

```
(declare some-func)
(defn other-func [] (some-func))
(defn some-func
  {:inline (fn [] "test-inline")}
  [] "test")
(other-func) ;;=> "test"
(defn other-func [] (some-func))
(other-func) ;;=> "test-inline"
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried Criterium as follows:

```
(ns speed-test.core
  (:require [criterium.core :as crit]))

(declare this)
(defn bench-this [] (crit/bench (this)))
(defn this [])

(defn that [])
(defn bench-that [] (crit/bench (that)))
```

I could find no significant difference between `bench-this` and `bench-that`. Since the average execution times are 7 - 8 ns in both cases, I get the feeling we're measuring the ghost of the nothing that HotSpot can't quite lay.